# Replacing whitespace in a list with comma and turning into sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
l={"1 atattaggtt tttacctacc caggaaaagc caaccaacct
61 ctctaaacga actttaaaat ctgtgtagct gtcgctcggc
121 gcagtataaa caataataaa"}
```

which I want to turn into:

```
{{{1,{"atattaggtt","tttacctacc","caggaaaagc","caaccaacct"}},
    {61,{"ctctaaacga","actttaaaat","ctgtgtagct","gtcgctcggc"}},
    {121,{"gcagtataaa","caataataaa"}}}
```

I wonder how one does this?

**Update:** I know that `StringReplace[l, WhitespaceCharacter -> ","]` gives me:

```
{"1,atattaggtt,tttacctacc,caggaaaagc,caaccaacct,61,ctctaaacga,\
actttaaaat,ctgtgtagct,gtcgctcggc,121,gcagtataaa,caataataaa"}
```

Yet I don't know how to sublist this as above.

Comment: try `StringSplit[lis, ","]`

Comment: @Nasser it was not a simple `StringSplit[]`

Comment: I was replying to  what you said `Yet I don't know how to sublist this as above.` not to the main question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html) with [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html).

```
StringCases[
  n : NumberString ~~ s : (WhitespaceCharacter ~~ LetterCharacter ..) .. :> 
    {FromDigits@n, StringSplit@s}
]@l
```

> ```
> {{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", "caaccaacct"}}, 
>   {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", "gtcgctcggc"}}, 
>   {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

```
{First[#], Rest[#]} & /@ ImportString[#, "Table"] & /@ l

(*    {{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", "caaccaacct"}},
        {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", "gtcgctcggc"}},
        {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}}                              *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way using regular expressions.

```
StringSplit[l, RegularExpression["(?=[A-Z]|(?<!\\d)\\d)"]] // 
  Map[StringSplit /* ({First@#, Rest@#} &), #, {-1}] &
```

Answer (score 3):

```
StringCases[l,
  RegularExpression["([1-9]+)([a-t\s]+)"]:> {"$1", StringSplit["$2"]}
]
```

> {{{1, {atattaggtt, tttacctacc, caggaaaagc, caaccaacct}}, {61, {ctctaaacga, actttaaaat, ctgtgtagct, gtcgctcggc}}, {121, {gcagtataaa, caataataaa}}}}

**Original Answer**

```
StringCases[l,RegularExpression["([1-9]+)([a-z\s]+)"]:> {"$1", "$2"}]
  // MapAt[StringSplit, #, {All,All,2}]&
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map[{FromDigits @ #, {##2}} & @@@ # & @* StringSplit] @ StringSplit[l, "\n"]
```

> ```
> {{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", "caaccaacct"}}, 
>   {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", "gtcgctcggc"}},
>   {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}}
> ```

Also

```
f = Normal[{#, DeleteCases[{##2}, ""]} & @@@ SemanticImportString[#]] &;
f /@ l
```

> ```
> {{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", "caaccaacct"}}, 
>   {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", "gtcgctcggc"}}, 
>   {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}}
> ```

and

```
f2 = {FromDigits @ #, {##2}} & @@@ 
      Split[StringSplit @ #, Not @* StringMatchQ[NumberString] @* First] &;
f2 /@ l
```

> ```
>  {{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", "caaccaacct"}},
>    {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", "gtcgctcggc"}},
>    {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

So after playing a bit, I found the solution:

```
x0 = StringSplit[l, Whitespace] // Flatten // ToExpression;
x1 = Split[x0, ! IntegerQ[#2] &];
x2 = Map[Drop[#, 1] &, x1];
x3 = Table[Map[ToString[#] &, x2[[i]]], {i, Length[x2]}];
x4 = Map[Take[#, 1] &, x1] // Flatten;
final = Transpose[{x4, x3}]
```

To which I get:

```
{{1, {"atattaggtt", "tttacctacc", "caggaaaagc", 
   "caaccaacct"}}, {61, {"ctctaaacga", "actttaaaat", "ctgtgtagct", 
   "gtcgctcggc"}}, {121, {"gcagtataaa", "caataataaa"}}}
```

As desired. Maybe you guys can make this more efficient.

Comment: Your 'as desired' differs somewhat to that given in your question